# Polynomially recurrent sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $P$ be a polynomial of $\mathbb R[x]$ of degree $d\ge2$. Consider the sequence $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ defined by $u_{n+1}=P(u_n)$. Assume that the sequence $(|u_n|)_n$ diverges to $+\infty$. Is it true that there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ such that $|u_n|\sim e^{\alpha d^n+o(d^n)}$ for $n\to+\infty$?

Comment: Can you clarify what is $|u_n|_n$? Which norm are you using?

Comment: @CalvinLin - I believe OP means $(|u_n|)_n$, namely the sequence $|u_n|$

Comment: It is the classical absolute value.

Comment: Ah, I was reading it as function composition of polynomials, not as a real number. A) It might help to define $u_1 \in \mathbb{R}$. B) Also, why not just $|u_n| $? -> Ah, I see you just edited this.